# Paginate views by first letter of Node title

Tags: views, paging

I'm creating a View of staff profiles. It's a simple list of Node's Title filed (which happens to be the person's name. Instead of paging by number of items, I want to group them by first letter of first name. How should I start this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Views comes with a nice default glossary view out of the box. Go to /structure/views/view/glossary/edit, enable it and set it to filter for your content type. viola.

And in case you are  wondering where the Magic happens then you would find it in the contextual filter MORE options.

[image]

Comment: Nigel Waters, I have taken the liberty to add a few more things to the answer hope that is fine with you. :-)

Comment: no problemo @Mohammed Shameem

Comment: This is wonderful. I found the glossary mode and can use that contextual filter. How does one go about building the attachment (pager) which lists the first letter?

Comment: Never mind. This is a clone and customize activity!

Comment: I have a follow up question about this regarding how to hide the number count in parenthesis next to the first letter pagination. As in how might I hide the count to only have the first letter... http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/60846/remove-count-from-glossary-view

Comment: See http://drupal.org/node/286340