# Remove count from glossary view

Tags: views

I have a situation where I need to remove (via client request) the letter count in the header of a view based on Glossary view. How might I remove the numbers (in parenthesis)

[image]

Previous question history: [Paginate views by first letter of Node title](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/59227/paginate-views-by-first-letter-of-node-title)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy `views-view-summary-unformatted.tpl.php` to your theme and edit the file and remove line 17 `(<?php print $row->count; ?>)`

or wrap line 17 `(<?php print $row->count; ?>)` with a span and hide it using css

```
<span>(<?php print $row->count; ?>)</span>
```

Answer (score 5):

- Go to the Attachment details of the Glossary view
- Under Contextual Filters (you may need to click Advanced to see it) click on "Content: Title"
- Uncheck "Display record count with link"

Answer (score 0):

Since I can't comment, I have to add an answer. I agree with Bill's answer. This also works for Drupal 8 and no code change is required. De-selecting "Display record count with link" will remove the parenthesis.